# Sysmon Event 17 not logging duplicate named pipes

Tags: windows, named-pipes

I am currently running Sysmon to do some logging for PipeEvents and notice that Sysmon does not seem to log pipe creation (Event 17) of pipes with the same name if the first pipe is still running.

For example, if process A created pipe `\test`, and process B was to create a pipe with the same pipe name `\test` without process A closing the pipe, Sysmon will only log the first instance of the pipe creation (i.e. process A's creation).

I tried the above scenario using PowerShell by executing the following command in two separate PowerShell instances.

```
$pipe=new-object System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeServerStream("\test", [System.IO.Pipes.PipeDirection]::InOut, 10)
```

My sysmon is set up with the following configuration (running in a VirtualBox VM and thus exclude the VBox pipes).

```xml
<Sysmon schemaversion="4.82">
    <HashAlgorithms>*</HashAlgorithms>
    <EventFiltering>
        <PipeEvent onmatch="exclude">
            <Image condition="contains">VBoxService.exe</Image>
            <Image condition="contains">VBoxTray.exe</Image>
        </PipeEvent>
    </EventFiltering>
</Sysmon>
```

I am wondering if there is any way to circumvent this issue so that we are able to log both instances of the pipe creation?

Thanks in advance!